# Internet Recovery - No progress

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, dual-boot, internet-recovery

I am trying to use internet recovery to install OS X Yosemite and dual boot it with High Sierra on my 2015 model 13-inch Macbook Pro, but I’m having some issues. I can boot into Internet Recovery, can choose an internet connection, but after doing that, *absolutely* ***nothing*** happens. The earth icon is still spinning, I can change to a different wifi, NOTHING happens. Is there anything I can do to start Internet Recovery properly? By the way, the computer already has High Sierra installed, and works properly.

Comment: How long are you waiting for the Earth globe to stop spinning?

Comment: I waited like 20 minutes and then posted this question. I restarted and tried again, waiting for 10 minutes. Should I wait longer?

Comment: How long it takes can depend on a number of factors, including the speed of your connection and how much needs to be downloaded, etc. I've seen instances where it can take a couple of hours or more, so I'd leave it for a while and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By the way, I’m trying to connect to internet via Thunderbolt 2 to Ethernet adapter. Can that be a reason?

Comment: Well, it could be. Do you know if you're actually connected? Have you tried connecting another way (e.g. via Wi-Fi)?

Comment: My computer is away from the WiFi so I always use ethernet. I’ll try going near the WiFi, retrying with it and post my results.

Comment: After waiting about 30 minutes near the WiFi, I got error code “-2002F”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75879/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-omer-rifat-kuldasli).